# When I include InsertListing in a form in admin fieldset, I get a vertical scrollbar

Tags: magento-2.1, layout, insertlisting

When I include **insert listing** in a fieldset in an admin form, I always get a vertical scrollbar like in the image. I think it's a problem with the width of the container, but I don't know how to fix this problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should add `<update handle="styles"/>` to layout.

The `styles.xml` will remove old css file:

```
<remove src="css/styles-old.css"/>
```

if you open `styles-old.css` you can see the css rule-set which broken you grid :

```
.admin__scope-old {
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. Can you tell me, which file I have to upsate???

Comment: You should update layout which handle this page. https://picua.org/image/download.xF2rbf